# Laravel 5.5.40 validation - check input ends with string (regex)

Tags: php, regex, laravel

i'm validating an email input like this:

```
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255'
```

I want my email to be in a specific domain, example: 1234@gmail.com

so it needs to end with the correct domain

I cannot find a solution nowhere, I have tried regex but i don't understand it and it doesn't seem to work in this case

```
    'regex:/(^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)?$)/u'
```

how can I validate it in this case? can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `regex:/(.+)@gmail\.com/i`

This means

`/` start of regex

`(.+)` any characters, but at least 1 character must be present (i.e. don't accept "@gmail.com" as an address)

`@gmail\.com` the domain with the dot escaped, because the dot is a special character in regex

`/` end of regex

`i` i option to make it case insensitive, so people can put GMAIL.com or gMail.com etc

Comment: Glad to help, please mark the answer as accepted. PS regex101.com offers a really easy way to test regex.